# Alguém poderia me informar o que acontece nesse método?

Tags: java, io

Eu tenho um método que faz algumas coisas que eu gostaria de saber o que é...só me explica por alto por favor?

```
 private static byte[] readFully(InputStream in) throws IOException {
      ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
      byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
      for (int count; (count = in.read(buffer)) != -1; ) {
         out.write(buffer, 0, count);
      }
      return out.toByteArray();

  }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

O método em questão está lendo todo o conteúdo de uma *stream* de entrada (e.g., de um arquivo, porta de rede, etc) para um array de *bytes* em memória.

O `ByteArrayOutputStream` é uma *stream* de saída que mantém tudo o que você escreve (`write`) em memória.

O código está basicando lendo o conteúdo da `InputStream` em blocos de até 1KiB (1024 bytes) e escrevendo-o no `ByteArrayOutputStream`. Essa é uma maneira bem manual de bufferizar a operação.

Finamente a linha `out.toByteArray()` retorna tudo o que foi escrito na `ByteArrayOutputStream` como um `byte[]`.

Veja que existem [diversas bibliotecas e implementações alternativas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1264709/convert-inputstream-to-byte-array-in-java) para resolver esse problema. O Java 9 inclusive incluirá um novo método [`InputStream.readAllBytes()`](http://download.java.net/java/jdk9/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html#readAllBytes--) com esse propósito.